# How to animate an element's "transform:rotate"?

Tags: css, transform, keyframe

The following CSS should theoretically work in the newest Chrome build... strangely enough, the opacity is animated properly but transform:rotate is ignored. Can this not be transitioned?

```
@-webkit-keyframes offblink {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.test {
  -webkit-animation-name: offblink;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Comment: it's working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/dwick/3zZbQ/

Comment: Works for me, too. (Chrome 12 on Mac OS).

Comment: Thanks, this helped pointing me to try inline-block for the target to be rotated. I had an inline span only.

Comment: transforms don't work on inline elements in webkit - although the spec says they should

Comment: @Michael: although the WebKit implementation came before the draft standard, so it’s not surprising it doesn’t follow it yet. The WebKit guys invented this stuff.

Comment: it's not 100% ready yet; that's why it still has the `-webkit-` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

Solved. I had this test-case:

```
<div>anim only this: <span class="test">+</span></div>
```

Only worked with adding this:

```
.test { display: inline-block; }
```